# Problem compiling PCSX-Reloaded

Tags: make, games, gtk2, emulators

I was trying to install pcsx 1.10 from source. After the configure step, make was executing until

```
 Utils.hpp:31:21: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

In file included from About.cpp:54:
Utils.hpp:31:21: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Then another one million of errors showed up. The file gtk.h is already present on:

```
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h
```

Tried another time, this time changing the configuration to include the environment variables made to detect gtk files:

```
./configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Pcsx-df-1.10/  --enable-nautilusburn=false  GTK2_CFLAGS=/usr/include/gtk-2.0/ GTK2_LIBS=/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/
```

This time the compilation process terminated with:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/: No such file: File format not recognized
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @NasirRiley  Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Ubuntu 10.4? That's long ago end of life. Before you begin, install a recent version like 19.04.

Comment: @NasirRiley I cannot do that

Comment: You need to install both gtk2-dev and gtk3-dev. There are also several other developer packages that you'll need. As you are still using Ubuntu 10.04, it's possible that some of those packages won't exist or will be too old to compile PCSX-Reloaded and that the libraries will be told for it to function properly. If you can't install a later version of Ubuntu, then there's nothing that you can do. EOL means just that.

Comment: @NasirRiley, gtk2-dev is already installed. Plus, PCSX is from 2009.

Comment: As I previously stated,there is also gtk3-dev. If this is your own computer, then there's no reason that you can't can't install the current versions of Ubuntu and PCSX. It looks like it's not that you can't but just that you won't.

Comment: @NasirRiley GTK3 is not supported. Even if it was, I do not know if it would work with pcsx. And I cannot move to newer versions due to the different graphic interface and lack of Gimp 2.6. About the security question, until someone can prove me I have reasonable chance of being attacked, I consider it acceptable. Plus I have little spare space on my hard drive (40GB disk, 6GB OS partition), if security updates takes much space, it would not be acceptable. Anyway, thanks for your effort

Comment: I suggest that you do a bit of research on IT security and the basics of maintaining an operating system and software. The OS that you are using EOL which means that it won't receive any security updates for any possible vulnerabilities of which there will many so there is a reasonable chance. The OS that you are using doesn't have anymore security updates to install and the current version of Ubuntu doesn't use up 40GB. Even it did, a 1TB HDD is $44 on Amazon. It's far better to just install a supported version of the OS than to run an unsupported version because of perceived difficulty.

Comment: @NasirRiley. $44 is 8-9x as much as I have available to spend. Not to mention the shipping cost. About " It's far better to just install a supported version of the OS than to run an unsupported version because of perceived difficulty": I will quote myself: "And I cannot move to newer versions due to the different graphic interface and lack of Gimp 2.6". The security part of your message is fairly standard stuff that I already know. Plus, quotting myself again: "About the security question, until someone can prove me I have reasonable chance of being attacked, I consider it acceptable"

Comment: I've already explained why you have a reasonable chance of being attacked. You are running an unsupported operating system that isn't receiving patches for security risks of which their are many. If you already know of this, they you are being willfully ignorant by continuing to run it and exposing yourself to those attacks. If you don't have money to upgrade, then that's your issue that you need to resolve. Continuing to run an unsupported operating system that's no longer receiving updates or security patches means that you aren't going to get much help.

Comment: @Nasir Riley. Prove that I have "you have a reasonable chance of being attacked" What is reasonable? Given that I never had any issues, before, I am willing to believe that the chances are not as reasonable as you seems to like to believe.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what anyone believes. You are running an unsupported operating system that isn't receiving security patches. You haven't had anything happen so far but the same was true of companies who have been hacked after doing the same. It's up to you, but don't expect any help.

Comment: The comparison is absurd since I am not a company. About the help, there will be some help, even though it won't be done by so many.

Comment: Yep. Only companies get hacked. It never happens to individuals............ Contrary to your claims, you know absolutely nothing about IT security.

Comment: False. Never claimed that only companies are hacked, only that using it to assess the probabilities of an individual being hacked is flawed. At least until you can show evidence that the chances are mildly similar. And another nice fallacy to say that " you know absolutely nothing about IT security". Even if it is true, there is no evidence whatever to assess it, even if the chances of myself being hacked are not small and if the chances of an individual and a company being hacked are similar. At maximum, one could say I know very little about IT security since it's a broad topic.

Comment: By the way, you did not explained how to move to another operating system that does not support the software that I need is going to be helpful.

Comment: Those are your problems, not anyone else's. You have decided to run an OS that's been EOL for years which is why you haven't gotten any help. I'm not going to repeat myself anymore or waste my time with the willfully ignorant. No one is going to help you if you won't even help yourself.

Comment: If these are my problems, then why you spend time trying to solve them? In fact all the questions presented here are someone's problem and not of anyone else. Your behavior is irrational according that line of thought. Your second statement is also false, since I did not say which OS I use until three days after the creation of the question. more likely no one knew the answer. I was helping myself trying to solve a secondary issue on my computer while keep using an OS that makes it useful for a user.

Comment: Of course, I should follow @NasirRiley tips, abandon the OS that makes the pc useful for one of the users, ruin his life. He will discount on me, ruining my life as a consequence. In the process, I can also spend $44, which might doing so I will not have money to pay the bills or buy food for using an OS that does not fulfill. Well, without eletrical energy, I guess I wouldn't need to worry about the security question. Brilliant! And call me an ignorant about security (which I am, as a layman) while not providing any substantial information about the probabilities of suffering an attack.